# How to iterate HashMap using JSTL forEach loop?

Tags: jsp, hashmap

In my Spring MVC application i have HashMap returned from my controllerServlet. Now I need to print that in my jsp using JSTL. Please help on this. I'm new in all this.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this,

suppose my MAP is :-

```
Map<String, String> countryList = new HashMap<String, String>();
countryList.put("United States", "Washington DC");
countryList.put("India", "Delhi");
countryList.put("Germany", "Berlin");
countryList.put("France", "Paris");
countryList.put("Italy", "Rome");

request.setAttribute("capitalList", countryList);
```

So in JSP ,

```
<c:forEach var="country" items="${capitalList}">
    Country: ${country.key}  - Capital: ${country.value}
</c:forEach>
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 8):

For accessing dynamic value from hash map you can use brace notation `[]`.

```
${someMap[dynamicKey]}
```

For example, consider [@Som's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257283/1031945) answer map

```
Map<String, String> countryMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
countryMap.put("United States", "Washington DC");
countryMap.put("India", "Delhi");
countryMap.put("Germany", "Berlin");
countryMap.put("France", "Paris");
countryMap.put("Italy", "Rome");

request.setAttribute("countryMap", countryMap);
```

#### JSP

Set key

```
<c:set var="keyName" value="India" />
```

pass the dynamic key

```
${countryMap[keyName]}
```

Or directly

```
${countryMap['United States']}
```

### See also

- [EL info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)