# How to access map key/value pair contained in a ModelMap object from jsp Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a ModelMap variable "model", the value object contained in the model map itself is a HashMap.

Controller code:

```
public String func(ModelMap model) 
{
    HashMap<String, List<String> aMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>();
    ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ....// give aList some data
    aMap.put("keystring", aList);
    model.addAttribute("aMap", aMap); 

    String view = "test";
    return view;
}
```

test.jsp code:

```
 var data = '${aMap}'; 
 // I know this gets the entire aMap including its key ("keystring") 
 // and the value (aList)
 var key ='${aMap}.key'; 
 alert(key); 
 var value ='${aMap}.value'; 
 alert(value);
```

I also tried:

```
 var va= data.key; // also tried data[key], data['key']
 alert(va);
```

but they all printed either an empty string or undefined.  However, if I printed "data", then I can see the entire map.

How do I access aMap's key ("keyString") and the value (aList) from test.jsp script part ?  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835683/how-to-loop-through-a-hashmap-in-jsp

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this solution
[How to iterate HashMap using JSTL forEach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257240/how-to-iterate-hashmap-using-jstl-foreach-loop)

It also seems that in your method should not be `@ResponseBody` since you are returning a view name.

Comment: I just tried adding  var key ='${aMap.key}';
       alert(key);
       var value ='${aMap.value}';
       alert(value),  but both returned me empty string.

Comment: var key ='${aMap.key}' - that construction does not make any sence, since aMap does not have a property key and value. Entry of a map has, but a map itself does not