# How does one convert the following hashMap<String, String> to a usable JS object?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jstl

Long story short.

I'm being given a hashMap from our back end team that has the following output.

{12=Other Services (Assisted), 2=Other Services, 4=Collect, 17=Get New (For Me), 19=Get New (For My Business)}

I'm a front end develop and have never worked with a string like this. I'm unable to split it using jquery.split() because of the '='

Searching online I found a lot of answers to my question but can't get it to work, if it is in fact the correct answer to my question.

Below is what I've tried. ${departmentHash} is an example. My actual code won't make a difference I suppose.

[How to iterate HashMap using JSTL forEach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257240/how-to-iterate-hashmap-using-jstl-foreach-loop)

```
<c:forEach var="department" items="${departmentHash}">
    Country: ${department.key}  - Capital: ${department.value}
</c:forEach>
```

The above didn't return anything in to ${department}

Other links had similar answers that I could not get to work.

[How to loop through a HashMap in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835683/how-to-loop-through-a-hashmap-in-jsp) 
[How to iterate an ArrayList inside a HashMap using JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117557/how-to-iterate-an-arraylist-inside-a-hashmap-using-jstl)

I might be wording my question wrong so if anyone has a correct link for me or an answer to my question it would be much appreciated.

Comment: convert it to json

Comment: You means that you can't split it on `,` then on `=` each result to get a key/value array ? That's a bit strange

Comment: @ScaryWombat Do we need to do that on the back end side? Having trouble with that on the front end because of the '='

Comment: @AxelH Thanks, I tried the split but it breaks on the '='. Back end guys refusing to escape characters.

Comment: *Do we need to do that on the back end side?* that would be easiest I thiink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing the string that you have provided wont work because of integers(12,2,4, etc) in the key section.

If you are getting the hashmap data in the form of a string, the you could try something like the following in javascript:

```
var str = '{12=Other Services (Assisted), 2=Other Services, 4=Collect, 17=Get New (For Me), 19=Get New (For My Business)}';

str = str.replace('{','');
str = str.replace('}','');// these lines will remove the leading and trailing braces

var arr = str.split(','); // this will give you an array of strings with each index in the format "12=Other Services (Assisted)"

arr.forEach(function(item){
    // here you can split again with '=' and do what is required
    var s = item.split('=');
    var obj = {key: s[0], value:s[1]}; // this is up to your implementation

})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Had to tweek it a TINY bit but it was exactly what I needed to finish it.

Comment: Glad to know that.