# Looping through a hash map Map<String, Object> in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap

Ho can i loop through a java hash map `Map<String, Object>` in JSP and display the output. I have seen posts regarding `Map<string, String>` but couldnt find anything for Object.
Can somebody post an example for the same.

Comment: Share the code for "I have seen posts regarding Map<string, String>" first with your problem statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835683/how-to-loop-through-a-hashmap-in-jsp  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257240/how-to-iterate-hashmap-using-jstl-foreach-loop  
Already answered !

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of Map iteration in JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${map}" var="item">
    <option value="${item.key}">${item.value}</option>
</c:forEach>
```